# fullpage.js, having larger sections and disable scrolling on some sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

jQuery plugin I am using with full documentation:
 https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

**What I want:** I am trying to have my second section disabled for the full page snap effect and also have it a larger height than a regular section (150vh etc.).

**Problems:** I have attempted it by adding it a new height to section 2

```
.ok{
  width:100%;
  height:2000px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

and also found some methods in the documentation to cancel the section snap:
`$.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false);`
 but when I scroll up and down, some of the sections snap back way too quick and is not fluid anymore.
(For example, scroll down to Section 2 then try scrolling to Section 1, it snaps back too quick)

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/kemtmm9a/30/

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    
     afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
  var loadedSection = $(this);
  if(index == 1){

$.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(true);   
  }
  //using index
  if(index == 2){

$.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false);   
  }
  if(index == 3){

$.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(true);   
  }
  //using anchorLink
  if(anchorLink == 'secondSlide'){
   alert("Section 2 ended loading");
  }
 }

});
```

```css
.section {
    text-align:center;
}
.ok{
  width:100%;
  height:2000px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.la{
  height:200%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section la">
        <div class="slide">Two 1</div>
        <div class="slide">Two 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section fp-auto-height"><div class="ok"></div>Three</div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue with your js code , check with below snippet

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
  anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage'],
  menu: '#menu',
  scrollingSpeed: 1000,
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
 var loadedSection = $(this);

 //using index
 if(index == 2){
  $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
 }

 //using anchorLink
 if(anchorLink == 'secondSlide'){
  alert("Section 2 ended loading");
 }
}
});
```

```css
.section {
    text-align:center;
}
.ok{
  width:100%;
  height:2000px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.la{
  height:200%;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide">Two 1</div>
        <div class="slide la">Two 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section fp-auto-height"><div class="ok"></div>Three</div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for.  I want the scrolling effect to be completely disabled in my second section.  It looks like on yours, everything is fluid.

Comment: @Snorlax hi i have disabled the scroling section 2 `two1` , is this what you need ?

Comment: No, I want 'section la' to have the scrolling jquery snap effect to be disabled, not have scrolling disabled.  For example, when you are in 'section la', I will have content in there that is 150vh, when scrolling in that 150vh section, I want the scrolling to behave as normal and then return to snapping when scrolling to the third section.